# Issue with webform used for adding and deleting customer names

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a web form which lists all of the customers and then gives you a text field with a button next to it where you can add customers. Then it should show the list of customers with delete buttons next to them where you can click to delete the customer from the database.

I'm having getting this to work. For starters it's echoing the contents of one of the PHP script. I'm not sure what I need to do.

Here's my index.php file:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "manager";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT url from customers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$tempArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tempArray[] = $row["url"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

<table>
 <tr>
   <td><u>URL</u></td>
   <td><u>Action</u></td>
 </tr>
 <?php foreach ($tempArray as $row) : ?>
 <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row; ?></td>
   <td><form action="disable_customer.php" method="get"><input type="submit" name="url" value="Disable Customer2"/></form></td>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<form action="add_customer.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="url"> <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Customer"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my add_customers.php file:

```
<html> <body>

Added <?php echo $_GET['url']; ?><br>

<?php

$servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = "test123"; $dbname = "manager";

// Create connection $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname); // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }

$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (url) VALUES ('$url')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully"; } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; }

$conn->close(); ?>

</body> </html>
```

Here's my disable_customer.php file:

```
<html>
<body>

<$php
session_start();
$SESSION['username']="Test";
$SESSION['authuser']=1;

$url = $_GET['url'];
echo "<br>" . $url . "<br>";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "test123";
$dbname = "manager";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if (isset($_REQUEST["btn_submit"])) {
    echo "yyyyaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaayyyyyyyyyy";
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.url = " . "'$url'";
echo "---------------------\n";
echo $sql . "\n";
echo "---------------------\n";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record successfully deleted.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be <?php on line:4 in disable_customer.php file not <$php

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that but now it echoes this                                                    --------------------- DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.url = 'Disable Customer2' --------------------- Record successfully deleted.

Comment: That's because you have echoed it here - `echo $sql . "\n";` and 4 lines around it. The record should have been deleted from your database right now.

Comment: You do need to apply the logic there, about what should your application do after deletion is completed.

Comment: *"Record successfully deleted"* - Great, then there's nothing else to do here.

Comment: Okay sorry I fixed that and now it says "Deleted Customer2" but it doesn't actually delete the customer record.

Comment: Your php is working fine. Something should have messed up with database. Try running your query directly in the database(phpadmin, if you're using one). `DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.url = 'Disable Customer2'`

Comment: I ran the following query from XAMPP:`DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.url = 'test2222'` This deleted the record but it doesn't delete a record when I click the button on the web form to delete. Do you think it's something with my php.ini file maybe. Register_globals is set to off

Answer (score 0):

try changing index.php from this:

```
<form action="disable_customer.php" method="get"><input type="submit" name="url" value="Disable Customer2"/></form>
```

to this:

```
<form action="disable_customer.php" method="get">
put the url in here: <input type="text" name="url"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

If that works - but you don't want the user to be entering their own urls - then you need to read those urls out of the database first:

Going back to your original code in index.php, change the foreach to output the value of the url into 'value' attribute of the button:

```
<?php foreach ($tempArray as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row; ?></td>
        <td><form action="disable_customer.php" method="get"><input type="submit" name="url" value="<? echo $row['url'] ?>"/></form></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. I tried your second suggestion because I don't want the user to have to type the name of the customer they want to delete. Now I get several buttons next to each user's name and each of the buttons have the following label:`<br /><b>Warning</b>: Illegal string offset 'ur' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />y`

Comment: Okay I think I figured this one out.