# PHP web form, used to add/remove customer names, not working correctly

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with a PHP web form that I can use to add or remove customer names from an SQL database. The "add_customer.php" page seems to work fine but the "disable_customer.php" isn't actually deleting the record. Here's what it says when I click the disable button:

```
Disable Customer2
Record successfully deleted.
```

"Disable Customer2" is the name of the button I'm clicking, not name of the customer I'm trying to delete.

**Here's the index.php file:**

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "manager";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT url from customers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$tempArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tempArray[] = $row["url"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

<table>
 <tr>
   <td><u>URL</u></td>
   <td><u>Action</u></td>
 </tr>
 <?php foreach ($tempArray as $row) : ?>
 <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row; ?></td>
   <td><form action="disable_customer.php" method="get"><input type="submit" name="url" value="Disable Customer2"/></form></td>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<form action="add_customer.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="url"> <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Customer"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here's the add_customer.php file:**

```
<html> <body>

Added <?php echo $_GET['url']; ?><br>

<?php

$servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = "test123"; $dbname = "manager";

// Create connection $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname); // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }

$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (url) VALUES ('$url')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully"; } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; }

$conn->close(); ?>

</body> </html>
```

**Here's the disable_customer.php file:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$SESSION['username']="Test";
$SESSION['authuser']=1;

$url = $_GET['url'];
echo "<br>" . $url . "<br>";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "test123";
$dbname = "manager";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

/*
if (isset($_REQUEST["url"])) {

    echo $_REQUEST['url'];
    echo "yyyyaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaayyyyyyyyyy";
}
*/

$sql = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.url = " . "'$url'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record successfully deleted.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there something not set right in my php.ini file maybe? It's almost like it's not passing the customer name between the index.php page and the disable_customer.php page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you don't pass customer name - what do you expect?

Comment: Please don't repost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321807/issue-with-webform-used-for-adding-and-deleting-customer-names

Comment: I'm sorry. I though the other question was dead since no one was answering my question in the comments. Can you help me with this please? How do I pass the customer name?

Comment: please read a tutuorial on basic forms. You aren't sending anything to the delete script that it could use to tell what record to delete. In a get form like yours you can see what you are sending. Is "Disable Customer2" really going to match a url in the database ?

Comment: All of the form tutorials I can find seem to tell me how to create a web form with text input fields. Can't seem to find one that tells me how to do a button to delete a database entry (with no text field). Can you recommend a tutorial that has this information? Or can you help me out?